# Lealefjs : Prevent Dragging Marker out of ImageLayer bounds

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm adding draggable markers on mapclick function. I don't give permission to put marker out of map with code below.

```
if (imageBounds.contains(newPosition)) {
    var newMarker = L.marker(newPosition).addTo(map);
}
```

But I can drag markers to out of imagelayer and I want to prevent this issue. Here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/xfdxe2ea/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I've edited your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xfdxe2ea/1/) to achieve what you want.

Basically, what I did is that I register an handler for the `drag` event, and then each time the handler is called, I check if the marker is still within the desired bounds. If it is, I store its position in a variable accessible through closure, this can be seen as the last known valid position.
If the marker position becomes "not valid " (outside the bounds), then I "manually" replace it to its last known valid position.

```
var lastValidPosition;
newMarker.on("drag", function(event) {
    var latLng = newMarker.getLatLng();
    if (imageBounds.contains(latLng)) {
        lastValidPosition = latLng;
    } else {
        if (lastValidPosition) {
            newMarker.setLatLng(lastValidPosition);
        }
    }
}, newMarker);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Stranded. Your solution is doing what I want. But there is a little problem. For example I'm dragging a marker to left side of map and ending pressing left mouse button. Then I hovered again that marker, I can still drag it. For ending this drag I must press left mouse button and it puts another marker on map.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want. The drag seems to work fine on my side (Chrome v45). If I'm dragging a marker but the mouse goes outside the bounds and then I click left, I can still add new markers  inside bounds, or drag previous ones, etc.

Comment: What I mean is this: I first drag the marker outside the bounds (and the cursor as well) while still clicking the left and unclick left while my cursor is outside the bounds. When I return my cursor to the map, the map still drags around the last marker even though I'm still not clicking anything. And when I click left this time, it pops up another marker, leaving the previous marker just where I click left. @Stranded

Comment: Ok so when you drag a marker and go outside the bounds and then you release your mouse's left button, then come back to the bounds you are still dragging the marker? I don't hae this behaviour on Chrome. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome. Do you think this is because of browser ? But I tried it also IE and same thing happened. @Stranded